# pointer reference without memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I tried executing the following code but it prints the address of x to be NIL.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int a=5;
int *x;
*x=a;
printf("%p  %p",&a,x);
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: x is just a pointer to and adress which is not known and not checked. Then you start to write into the referenced area the value 5. I think you want to give the adress of a to x. So you have to do `x = &a`. Try reading a bit more about pointers to make it clearer